# How can i store a file in the build folder of jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I use jenkins and some builds generate files (in the workspace) wich will be used by a post build custom plugin (the plugin runs perfectly).

Now I want to store this file in the build folder of my job, so I am able to read it when there is a build failed (using the lastSuccessfulBuild folder) (the read will not be done by the post action plugin).

So my question is: how can I store this generated file in the build folder?

Thank you.

Comment: @MoralesBatovski How is that an homework?

Comment: No it is absolutely not an homework. It is for my work ;-) And if have not yet found the solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can archive artifacts as a post-build action. Just specify the path / pattern of the file(s) in your workspace and it will archive the file under JobName/builds/buildNumber/archive.

[image]

Just make sure the post-build action to archive the artifacts is before the post-build action to read the artifacts.

Comment: To use this properly he will need to install : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin. But archiving is always the answer for keeping artifacts per build. +1

Answer (score -1):

**Use File parameter in General configuration**

File parameter help document says:
Accepts a file submission from a browser as a build parameter. The uploaded file will be placed at the specified location in the workspace, which your build can then access and use.

This is useful for many situations, such as:

Letting people run tests on the artifacts they built.
Automating the upload/release/deployment process by allowing the user to place the file.
Perform data processing by uploading a dataset.
The name of the submitted file is available in the environment variable whose name is the same as file location. For example, if you set the file location to be abc.zip, then ${abc.zip} would give you the original file name passed from the browser (such as my.zip.) The name will not include the directory name portion.

File upload is optional. If a user chooses not to upload anything, Jenkins will simply skips this parameter and will not place anything (but it also will not delete anything that's already in the workspace.)